# How to delete instantiation of a member function template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am learning how to stop instantiation of a member function template. In c++20 requires clause is used to put constraint on template arguments and using this I am able to stop instantiation in c++20.

What line of code could replace the requires clause in c++11/14/17 in this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct St {
    template<typename T>
    // C++11/14/17 ???
    requires ( !(std::is_same<T, bool>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)) // C++20
    constexpr auto increment_by_one(T targ) const noexcept { return targ+1; }

};

int main() {
    St s;
    std::cout << s.increment_by_one(5) << '\n';
    std::cout << s.increment_by_one(8.6) << '\n';
    std::cout << s.increment_by_one(6.6f) << '\n';
    //std::cout << s.increment_by_one(true) << '\n';
    //std::cout << s.increment_by_one(std::string("test string")) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/vjc5cE

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but you may be looking for [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

Comment: Be careful declaring functions as `noexcept`. Once you do, you can't revoke it without breaking your interface (someone may be relying on the `noexcept` guarantee) and you can paint yourself into a corner. What if your function eventually supports a type where `+1` is not `noexcept`? As a rule destructors, swap functions and move constructors/operators should be `noexcept`. Other than those, there should be a  reason for adding `noexcept`. Don't use it just because you can.

Comment: I want to stop instantiation of member function template "increment_by_one" for bool and string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the type trait `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// ...

    template<typename T,
        typename std::enable_if<
          !(std::is_same<T, bool>::value || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value),
          int
        >::type = 0
    >
    constexpr auto increment_by_one(T targ) const noexcept -> decltype(targ+1) {
        return targ+1;                                  //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }                                                   // trailing return type
```

Note that before C++14 you need to add a trailing return type if you're using `auto`.